# memory marshalling - program can't find C++ dll in csharp plugin

Tags: c#, c++, dll, cmake, interop

The program is silently failing. It attempts to marshal memory to the c++ dll and gets nothing back, it does this with and without the c++ dll in the plugin dir which is why I think it can't find the c++ dll.

1. c++ dll (bla.dll) is targeting win32. cmake generated project files.
2. c# wrapper dll is built as a nuget package and is targeting x86, csproj files configured by configure_file in cmake. plugin dll is targeting x86. loads c# wrapper dll as nuget file. c++ dll is included as a lib in the nuget package.
3. c# plugin dll installs the nuget c# wrapper and is loaded by the main program.
4. main program is x86 exe and is very large

The csproj for c# wrapper includes the c++ dll like the following:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="${blablacmakeconfigurefilevariable}/bin/blad.dll" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        <Pack>true</Pack>
        <PackagePath>lib\net472\blad.dll</PackagePath>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="${blablacmakeconfigurefilevariable}/bin/bla.dll" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        <Pack>true</Pack>
        <PackagePath>lib\net472\bla.dll</PackagePath>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

the c# wrapper links to the c++ dll with the following:

```
#if DEBUG
        [DllImport("blad.dll", EntryPoint = "Solve", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
#else
        [DllImport("bla.dll", EntryPoint = "Solve", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
#endif
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler, MarshalTypeRef = typeof(CppreturntypeMarshaller))]
        private static extern Cppreturntype Solve( 
            [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler, MarshalTypeRef = typeof(CppinputtypeMarshaller))] Cppinputtype input)
```

This works in debug with a debugger attached to the program.

When I build the c# plugin I get a warning during one of the msbuild tasks.

```
Resolved file has a bad image, no metadata, or is otherwise inaccessible. System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'blad.dll' or one of it's dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
```

I know this means it's setup wrong but I'm not sure how to fix. I think it's because of how i'm adding the dll to the csproj because of the PackagePath hack to get it included in the nuget package.

Because it's a plugin I'm assuming the relative c++ dll location is wrong and so I need to properly specify it. How do I do that?

I'm also wondering if the debug/release differentiation is wrong too.

Comment: If it couldn't find it you would get a `DllNotFoundException` or a `EntryPointNotFoundException`. What is the definition of the C++ code? And what is the code for `CppinputtypeMarshaller` and `CppreturntypeMarshaller`?

Comment: the code for the marshallers is long and working with a debugger attached so I'm very confident the issue is not there. The main program running the plugin is large and I think it's swallowing lots of exceptions so that may be why I'm not seeing that exception.

Comment: OK what does it do roughly? Let's see the header for the C++ function, it's not answerable without that.

Comment: How would it work in debug if the issue is there? it just takes the input and returns an output.
__declspec( dllexport ) void * Solve( void *input);

Comment: there's no small reproduceable portion of marshalling that I can share. i'm using the interop c# stuff to create intptr using custom marshalling where necessary and all the c# types are sequential, the cpp handles the custom to read in and send back out. There's unit tests on the csharp marshalling to/fro all passing, there are mocks i can run where I can see the data coming in from the c++ dll. There are unit tests on the cpp side passing plus the whole thing with the real plugin works on my machine but just not on another machine. The error is within the information I've given.

Answer (score 0):

aside from everything almost certainly not being setup correctly, the cause of failure was runtime setup. The other machines didn't have the right Redistributable Packages installed. Building everything in release also resolves this.